# PHP multidimensional array into JSON object without indexes showing

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have form output coming from repeater looking like this:

```
array:2 [ 0 => array:1 ["participant_name" => "John" ], 0 => array:1 ["participant_name" => "Jane" ]]
```

I need to make from this JSON object looking like this:

```
{{"participant_name":"John"},{"participant_name":"Jane"}}
```

So far I tried `$participantsJson = json_encode( array_values($participants) , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`
but I'm always getting this shape

```
 {"0":{"participant_name":"John"},"1":{"participant_name":"Jane"}}
```

How to get rid of those indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is tto complex, use the immediate approach:

```
<?php
$input = [
  ["participant_name" => "John" ], 
  ["participant_name" => "Jane" ],
];
$output = json_encode($input);
var_dump($output);
```

The output is:

```
string(57) "[{"participant_name":"John"},{"participant_name":"Jane"}]"
```

Not that the output is an *array* encoded in JSON format...

Your question demonstrates an encoded *object* instead, but that is invalid JSON. Reason is that properties inside an object need to have a *name* , that is how objects are defined. You cannot have an object holding members without a name (what you called an "index" in your question).